# XOR encryption in payloads

Tags: c, encryption, malware

So i was working on a simple payload encryption using xor project

here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

VOID XorByOneKey(IN PBYTE pShellCode, IN SIZE_T sShellCodeSize, IN BYTE bKey) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sShellCodeSize; i++) {
        pShellCode[i] = pShellCode[i] ^ bKey;
    }
}

int main() {
    HRSRC hRsrc = NULL;
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = NULL;
    PVOID pPayloadAddress = NULL;
    SIZE_T sPayloadSize = NULL;

    // Get the location to the data stored in .rsrc by its id *IDR_RCDATA1*
    hRsrc = FindResourceW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
    if (hRsrc == NULL) {
        // in case of function failure
        printf("[!] FindResourceW Failed with Error : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Get the handle of the specified resource data since it is required to lock resource later
    hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, hRsrc);
    if (hGlobal == NULL) {
        // in case of function failure
        printf("[!] LoadResource Failed with Error : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Get the address of our payload in .rsrc section
    pPayloadAddress = LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (pPayloadAddress == NULL) {
        // in case of function failure
        printf("[!] LockResource Failed With Error : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Get the size of our payload in .rsrc section
    sPayloadSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hRsrc);
    if (sPayloadSize == NULL) {
        // in case of function failure
        printf("[!] SizeofResource Failed with Error : %d\n ", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    PVOID pTmpBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sPayloadSize);
    if (pTmpBuffer != NULL) {
        // copying the payload from the resource section
        memcpy(pTmpBuffer, pPayloadAddress, sPayloadSize);
    }
    int i = 0;
    XorByOneKey((PBYTE)pTmpBuffer, sPayloadSize, i);

    // Printing the base address of the buffer
    printf("[i] pTmpBuffer var : 0x%p \n", pTmpBuffer);

    // Printing pointer and size to screen
    printf("[i] sPayloadAddress var : 0x%p \n", pPayloadAddress);
    printf("[i] sPayloadSize var : 0x%ld \n", sPayloadSize);
    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However when i check the pTmpBuffer address using a debugger the shellcode their is not encrypted the shell code remains the same i have loaded the shellcode into the .rsrc section i am on Visual Studio 2022.

Any help would be appreciated

Tried moving the print message around to see if it was old but did not work

Comment: `xor` with a zero key doesn't do anything.

Comment: so should using 1 one work

Comment: Sure. Zero has all bits cleared, which means that `x ^ 0 == x`. That's not true for any other key value.